# What is the algebraic form of the momentum eigenstate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, operators, momentum

I'm asking this in the context of trying to verify the equation $a^{\dagger}_{p} \vert 0 \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}} \vert p \rangle$.
So far I have calculated

1. $\vert 0 \rangle = e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2m\omega_p}$ (omitting normalization)
2. $a^{\dagger}_{p} \vert 0 \rangle = \sqrt{2m\omega_p}x e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2m\omega_p}$

Then when I try to apply $\hat{p} = -i \frac{d}{dx}$ onto $\sqrt{2\omega_p} a^{\dagger}_{p} \vert 0 \rangle$ to check that it is a momentum eigenstate, I get an eigenvalue that does not look anything like momentum. Is this the right way to check the equation? What does the momentum eigenstate look like? The eigen-equation $\hat{p} \vert p \rangle = p \vert p \rangle$ says that the solution is $\vert p \rangle = Ae^{ipx}$, but this looks very different from the algebraic form of $\sqrt{2\omega_p} a^{\dagger}_{p} \vert 0 \rangle$

Comment: I don't have time to write a good answer now, but you are confusing eigenstates of the single particle harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian which don't have a definite momentum with excitations of a quantum field which do have a definite momentum. In these two cases, the ground states as well as the creation operators are different. Check out a quantum field theory textbook to distinguish between the quantum mechanics of particles and the quantum mechanics of fields

Comment: I'm using Schwartz's QFT textbook, which simply states the first equation without a derivation. I highly doubt it is supposed to be taken as an axiom of QFT, because operators and state vectors usually have an algebraic form, therefore I'm trying to work it out from its constituent quantities.

Comment: The RHS of your 1. and 2. are not states. Are the $a_p$ harmonic oscillator modes or quantum field modes? Where do these exponentials come from? I don't understand what this question is about.

Comment: Can you clarify which equations in Schwartz you are using?

Comment: The first equation is 2.70.

Answer (score 1):

You are making confusion between operators and their representations on the position basis. Your hypotheses 1) and 2) are wrong (more ill-interpreted): as you can easily notice the left hand sides contain an element in the Hilbert space whereas the right hand sides contain numbers (functions evaluated in a point $x$, therefore a number).

To answer your question: 
$$
a^{\dagger}_p |0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}}|p\rangle
$$
therefore, by *definition*
$$
\hat{p}\sqrt{2\omega_p}\,a^{\dagger}_p |0\rangle = \hat{p}\,\sqrt{2\omega_p}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}}|p\rangle= \hat{p}\,|p\rangle = p\,|p\rangle.
$$
Your errors start from the fact that you mistake the state by its own wave function, which are two different things. The state $|\psi\rangle$ is an element of a Hilbert space, whereas its wave function is the scalar product of such element on the position basis $\psi(x)=\langle x | \psi\rangle$. Likewise the momentum operator is **not** the derivative with respect to $x$, rather its representation $\langle x|\hat{p}|\psi\rangle=-i\hbar\dot{\psi}(x)$ is.

Comment: Where did the first equation come from? What you wrote makes it sound like you take it as a postulate of the theory.

Comment: A state $|p\rangle$ is by definition a one particle state with momentum $p$; as such, it is created by the action of $a_p^{\dagger}$ on the vacuum. The rest in just a normalisation factor.

Comment: Do you mean there is no way to derive this relation?

Comment: It is the definition of the operator $a_p^{\dagger}$ as acting on the vacuum. $a_p^{\dagger}|0\rangle = N |p\rangle$, with N to be determined calculating the norm = 1.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem here is that you are confusing quantum mechanics of a single harmonic oscillator with quantum field theory, which is quantum mechanics of a field and can also be considered as quantum mechanics of an infinite number of harmonic oscillators. In quantum mechanics of a single oscillator, the ground state $|0\rangle$ can be represented as:

$$|0\rangle \dot{=} \langle x|0\rangle=\biggr(\frac{m\omega}{\pi\hbar}\biggr)^{1/4}e^{-\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}x^2}$$

If we define the raising operator

$$a^\dagger = \sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}}\biggr(x-\frac{i}{m\omega}p\biggr)$$

then the first excited state of the harmonic oscillator is

$$a^\dagger |0\rangle=|1\rangle$$

Indeed, this is not a momentum eigenstate. Due to the lack of translational invariance of the harmonic oscillator potential, you wouldn't expect a stationary state of the Hamiltonian to have a definite momentum.

Now, if we move away from the harmonic oscillator and consider instead quantum mechanics of a field, the ground state $|0\rangle$ means something different. It refers to the ground state of a field. Likewise, the raising and lowering operators mean something different. They act on the states of the entire field and create particles with definite momenta. Also, the momentum operator that acts on a field is not $-i\frac{d}{dx}$. This is the momentum operator for a single harmonic oscillator. Therefore, you were confusing two different physical systems in your question. To learn more about the quantum mechanics of fields, read Schwartz again or read Peskin and Schroeder.

Answer (score 0):

It you are working with second quantization (quantum field theory), then what you wrote under "1." and "2." is incorrect. Your physical degrees of freedom are not coordinates $x$, but rather field variables $\phi$. So,

$$ \left| 0 \right> \sim \exp \left\{ -\frac{1}{2} \int d^3 x \phi(x)^2 \right\} $$

This object should be called wave functional (instead of a function), because it depends not on a single coordinate $x$ like in first quantization, but on the whole (continuous) set of variables $\phi(x)$, where $x$ is **just a label**.

Comment: Do not mistake the state with its wave function anyway. Your left hand side is correctly a state, whereas your right hand side is a wave function, namely the scalar product of the state onto the position basis $\langle x|\phi\rangle$. I understand what you mean but the notation is incorrect.